# When to compile PyQt5 resources and ui files when releasing a PyPI python package?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, setuptools, pypi

Use Case:

- I'm developing a PyQt5-based GUI application that I want to deploy using setuptools (setup.py)
- The package includes `.ui` and `.qrc` files that need to be compiled before running the application
- The application should work out of the box, no matter if installing from a `.whl` file, or from source by using `python setup.py install` or `pip install -e .` in editable mode

Question:
What is the right strategy to compile those resource files?

- During installation? (When/how exactly?)
- When running it the first time? (But then the installed PyPI package would need to add files to itself in-place, is this allowed/desired?)

Comment: see https://pypi.org/project/setup_qt/

Comment: @eyllanesc: Does this mean, everyone will have to install `setup_qt` before they can install my package? That'd be annoying, there must be a better way.